# I changed the original scroll style to my custom styles and i have some white pixels in the bottom

Tags: html, css, scroll

[This the react-bootstrap modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iPCM.png)

[This is the scroll custom styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwGgm.png)

[This is the white pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFMwn.jpg)

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change background of scrollbar-track to transparent;
2. Give padding for text, cause maybe it's a letter;
3. There is possibility that's it a line from bootstrap modal footer, check it, and change if so